# Is F# ready for production environment?

Tags: f#

I believe a functional language would be helpful for the domain my company works in (financial) where we read in a ton of data, do some mathematical processing on it, and then store it again. Something which is fundamentally very parallelizable and not well-suited to extensive object-graphs with state (in my estimation).

As a .NET shop, I immediately thought of F# but I'm wary of the fact that the words "research" are prominently interspersed throughout almost all of the MS materials on it.

Does anyone know if F# is going to be something which MS is going to support going forward or would I be better of trying to convince the powers that be to go with Scheme/Haskell/et al?

Comment: F# is based on OCaml which is many years old.

Comment: Several years on; the answer to this question is still unclear to me :( I blogged some of my concerns: http://blog.dantup.com/2014/04/is-fsharp-ready-for-production/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is going to be in visual studio 2k10 as a formal language.

(See e.g.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/12/10/fsharp-to-ship-as-part-of-visual-studio-2010.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/05/20/visual-studio-2010-beta1-with-f-is-now-available-plus-matching-f-ctp-update-for-vs2008.aspx )

Comment: What's the advantage of 2k10 to 2010? They are both 4 chars. VS 10 or VS X seem better.

Comment: You're right there's not.  when speaking around here, we tend to call it 2k10, so instinctively I just wrote it that way.

Comment: Let's compromise and use the C++ naming method: Visual Studio 2K1X.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft seems to be really gung-ho about promoting F# as a first-class language in the new Visual Studio, so I expect that they will continue supporting it with tools and documentation for quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

See also e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966039/which-companies-are-using-f-internally-and-what-are-they-using-it-for

which is suggestive of a few big companies that are already using F#.

Comment: I saw that and the "accepted answer" didn't really mention any companies. I should have kept reading. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised to get accepted on that one, but I think I must have answered his implicit question - which is sort of the same as yours.